# Robot Model does not exist,

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, world

[image: Error in RVIZ]

I am using the [ROS2 humble SPOT](https://github.com/bdaiinstitute/spot_ros2) github repo, while installing the package in the workspace and running my first command, I came across this problem.

I tried to check the launch file for any wrong files path but found everything in it's place.

I did not encounter any problems during the installation and everything went well, How can I fix this error and include the world frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from the launch file that you might have to declare a static transform frame called "world", and connect that to the link "body". You can try this out using the following bit of code in the launch file:

```
import os
import typing

import launch
import launch_ros
from launch.substitutions import (
    Command,
    FindExecutable,
    LaunchConfiguration,
    PathJoinSubstitution,
)

pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package="spot_description").find("spot_description")
default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, "urdf/spot.urdf.xacro")
default_rviz2_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, "rviz/viz_spot.rviz")


def launch_setup(context: launch.LaunchContext) -> typing.List[launch_ros.actions.Node]:
    namespace = LaunchConfiguration("namespace").perform(context)

    robot_description = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_share, "urdf", "spot.urdf.xacro"]),
            " ",
            "arm:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("arm"),
            " ",
            "tf_prefix:=",
            LaunchConfiguration("tf_prefix"),
            " ",
        ]
    )

    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}],
        namespace=namespace,
    )

    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="joint_state_publisher",
        executable="joint_state_publisher",
        name="joint_state_publisher",
        namespace=namespace,
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration("gui")),
    )
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        executable="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        name="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration("gui")),
        namespace=namespace,
    )
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["-d" + default_rviz2_path],
    )

    static_tf_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "world", "body"]
    )

    return [
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node,
        static_tf_node
    ]


def generate_launch_description() -> launch.LaunchDescription:
    launch_arguments = [
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name="gui", default_value="True", description="Flag to enable joint_state_publisher_gui"
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name="model", default_value=default_model_path, description="Absolute path to robot urdf file"
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name="rvizconfig", default_value=default_rviz2_path, description="Absolute path to rviz config file"
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument("arm", default_value="false", description="include arm in robot model"),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "tf_prefix", default_value='""', description="apply namespace prefix to robot links and joints"
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument("namespace", default_value="", description="Namespace for robot tf topic"),
    ]

    return launch.LaunchDescription(launch_arguments + [launch.actions.OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup)])
```

**EDIT** Added the whole launch file to show the changes a bit better

Comment: I tried adding this code to the launch file "spot_description/launch/description.launch.py", but it did not work, it sais "Node" is undefined.

Comment: Yes, you needed to assign it to a variable and then call it in the return. I have updated my answer to show the full piece of code. This change would happen in the `launch_setup` function. Let's see if this works

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you for the help and for EDIT. really apprciated